# Laravel blade adding "`{ }`" to data when trying to allow HTML

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm trying to escape html in Laravel blade file it adds unnecessary "{ }" to it for some reason. This only happens when I'm escaping HTML by adding this `!!` before and after the variable.

blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')
<form action="{{ url('/save') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <textarea class="description" name="description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea.description',
        width: 900,
        height: 300
    });
</script>

<div id="products">
    @foreach($products as $product)

        {{!! $product->descr !!}}
        <br>
    @endforeach
</div>

@endsection
```

Output on the website with `!!` added

```
{this is a random description!}
```

How do I remove this?

Comment: Check out the section called "Displaying Unescaped Data": https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data, you only need single braces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using this `{{!! ... !!}}` and it must be like this `{!! ... !!}` (must be single curly brackets)

```
{!! '<p>Paragraph</p>' !!}
```

Comment: I Glad help you !